# What's wrong with Wolfram Alpha (or me)? Integral involving exp(-t)

Tags: calculus, wolfram-alpha

The integral in question

$\int e^{-t}\cdot (1+e^{-t})^{-2}dt$

can be solved with an easy $u$-substitution. I'm getting $(1+e^{-t})^{-1}$ which I can verify is correct by derivation. I'm rusty though and I wanted to verify the solution I obtained with W.A.:

[link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28e%5E%28-x%29%2a%281%2be%5E%28-x%29%29%5E%28-2%29%29)

It says $-\frac{1}{1+e^t}$ which can't be right since that's a negative function for all t. The integrand is nonnegative, so no way that's the answer.

What is going on here? Anyone have an explanation?

EDIT: Mathematica 5.2 is outputting the same thing as WA.

Comment: your answer is not negative of WA's answer!

Comment: @Maesumi I know! (Did I make that claim somewhere above?)

Comment: Sasha: I misunderstood, the solution below gives the correct explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indefinite integral is only defined up to addition of a constant. Now

$$1 - \frac{1}{1+e^t} = \frac{e^t}{1+e^t} = \frac{1}{e^{-t}+1}$$

is precisely your result.

Comment: Wait, you can choose a constant and then thrown on a +C? Isn't there some "fundamental output" of an indefinite integral? If I gave W.A's answer on a quiz, I guarantee my prof wouldn't see it and mark it wrong. Anyway, thanks for the heads up. Btw, did my explanation about the negative/positive functions make sense?

Comment: An indefinite integral is either any primitive of the integrand, or, sometimes, the set of all primitives. If you give the set of all primitives, the $+ C$ is mandatory, if you give any one primitive, you are free to pick whichever constant you like most. The integrand being positive does not mean that the indefinite integral has to be positive, only that it must be an increasing function.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, W.A. gave a primitive of its choosing and the +C!

Comment: Ah, so it gave the set of all primitives. Whether you get $-\frac{1}{1+e^t} + C$ or $\frac{1}{1+e^{-t}} + C$ depends on how you substitute and solve. A system like WA probably first brings the integrand into some normal form, and then applies the standard techniques, while a human is more flexible and sees how a standard technique can be applied without transforming the integrand first.